# How to search in a tree?

Tags: python, search, tree, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I have this follow tree implementation:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, *, val):
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(val={})".format(type(self).__name__, self.val)


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, *, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(val={}, left={}, right={})".format(type(self).__name__, self.val, self.left, self.right)
```

Now I try to add a method that checks if a element exists:

```py
def exists(self, val):
    if self.val == val:
        return True
    return self.left.exists(val) or self.right.exists(val)
```

Then if I try to search `1`, it's fine. But with `2`, It errors out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 30, in <module>
    print(tree.exists(2))
  File "...", line 20, in exists
    return self.left.exists(val) or self.right.exists(val)
  File "...", line 20, in exists
    return self.left.exists(val) or self.right.exists(val)
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

For reference, here's the tree I made:

```
tree = Tree(val=1,
            left=Tree(val=Node(val=2), left=Node(val=3), right=Node(val=4)),
            right=Tree(val=Node(val=2), left=Node(val=3), right=Node(val=4)))
```

How can I recursively search in a tree?

Comment: Your Node class is quite unnecessary. Just make the right and left subtrees `Tree` instances themselves. How else could they then have children od themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just jettison the Node class which serves no purpose whatsoever:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, *, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def exists(self, val):
        if self.val == val:
            return True
        if self.left and self.left.exists(val):
            return True
        if self.right and self.right.exists(val):
            return True
        return False 

tree = Tree(val=1,
            left=Tree(val=2, left=Tree(val=3), right=Tree(val=4)),
            right=Tree(val=2, left=Tree(val=3), right=Tree(val=4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom of you recursion is not only if you found the value (if self.val == val) but also if you reach a leaf of your tree (if self.isLeaf return false)

Comment: Your remark is correct, but you may want to elaborate more on your answer, providing more details to help. Could you please edit your answer to provide such required details? Please also take time to consider formatting your answer so the coding parts appear clearly from the text. Thank you for participating in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

The error says "Node" doesn't have a method "exists" which is correct. You didn't write Node's version of "exists." You need to work out what data and method belong to each node, and what data and methods should be on the tree as a whole.

But additionally, you can't look at left or right without checking to see if they are None.

```
self.left.exists()
```

should be replaced with

```
self.left and self.left.exists()
```

And the same for right